# Array value and index migration

Tags: php

My array is like:

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => "name"
        [1] => "zxczxc5"
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => "about"
        [1] => "zxczxc"
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => "contact"
        [1] => "zxczxc"
    )

)
```

I want to generate another array like this :

```
  Array
       {
            ['name']="zxczxc5";
       }
  Array
       {
            ['contact']="zxczxc";
       }
  Array
       {
            ['about']="zxczxc";
       }
```

I want the first array index zero value goes as the index of second value in my new array.

Thanks.

Comment: your example shows three arrays in the result instead of one, are you sure about that?

Comment: the output will be in an array..i missed it..

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to solve what you want to achieve, this is just one of those:

```
foreach ($array as &$pair) {
    $pair = call_user_func_array('array_combine', $pair);
}
unset($pair);
print_r($array);
```

It makes use of [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you name your first Array $aTest:

```
foreach($aTest as $aElement)
{
    $aNewArray[$aElement[0]] = $aElement[1];
}

print_r($aNewArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $newArray[$value['0']] = $value['1'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first array is called $array

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $element)
{
    $new_array[] = array($element[0] => $element[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($arr as $val) {
  $newArr[$val[0]] = $val[1];
}
```